# In yaml how to get value of output variable from powershell script then pass it to another template

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps Yaml build pipeline.  The yaml file calls a PowerShell script, like so:

```
- task: PowerShell@1
  name: SetBuildNumber
  displayName: 'Set Build Number'
  inputs:
    scriptName: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BuildScripts\UpdateBuildNumber.ps1'
```

This powershell script is supposed to output the value of a variable.  Here's what I have there:

```
Write-Output '##vso[task.setvariable variable=updatedCounter;isOutput=true]$(updatedCounter)'
```

`&updatedCounter` is a variable in that script that gets set to a number.  I want the yaml file that called it to then be able to use that number in a parameter sent to another file.  This is what I have for that:

```
- template: ${{ variables.buildtemplate }}
  parameters:
    BuildVersion: ${{ variables.BuildVersion }}$[SetBuildNumber.updatedCounter]
```

But what is getting passed to the template is the value of the BuildVersion variable concatenated with the string "$[SetBuildNumber.updatedCount]".  So it ends up like this, for example, where the value of `variables.BuildVersion` is "1.2.3.":

> "1.2.3.$[SetBuildNumber.updatedCounter]"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output variables can be referenced by macro syntax: `$()`, so it should be:

```
BuildVersion: ${{ variables.BuildVersion }}$(SetBuildNumber.updatedCounter)
```

This will only work if you reference output variable from the same stage and same job. In that case, you could also remove `isOutput=true` and simply use `$(updatedCounter)`.

If the reference takes place in a different stage or job, then the syntax is a bit [more complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job).

Comment: Yes - so I changed the reference to macro syntax as you describe.  I also changed that line in the script file to use Write-Host, "$updatedCounter" as the output, and using double-quotes instead of single-quotes.  Now it works!